# Is there a way to export an array as a gif in Julia?

Tags: julia, gif

I have an array that can easily be reshaped to contain Colors.jl or any other type. All gif making utilities I have found are either a part of SFML.jl which is a bit overkill for me or a plotting package. I simply want to make a gif file where one of the array's dimensions is time and the others colors, x and y.

Comment: This was crossposted to the [discourse message board](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/is-there-a-way-to-export-an-array-as-a-gif-in-julia/3662), where it has gotten some answers.

Comment: Note that crossposting (especially without an explicit reference) is discouraged.

Comment: Cross posting between SE sites is discouraged on SE.
Is there a policy of the julia discourse wrt it?
I am personally all for cross posting. I agree it *should* have links, at least in a comment at both ends.

Comment: I think crossposting is ok, but please answer yourself this question with the solution you used from the answers at Julia's forum, so this quiestion can be marked as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tim holy gave an excellent answer on the discourse thread.

```
using FileIO, Colors, FixedPointNumbers
img = rand(RGB{N0f8}, 200, 200, 30);
save("/tmp/test.gif", img, fps=5)
```